# Class "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\User" not found

Tags: laravel

How do I resolve this Laravel error?

```
Class "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\User" not found
```

I am creating a register for a blog and I am using the following:

```
User::create([
  'name' => $request->name,
  'username' => $request->username,
  'email' => $request->email,
  'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
])
```

I have included `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;`
and
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what User is (import namespace), because it is looking for it inside Auth, but User is a Model.

```
use App\Models\User;
```

or

```
use App\User; // older Laravel versions
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `use Auth;` only because the aliases is present most of the time in `app.php`

Try importing the User model in your controller as well.

```
use App\User;
```